# What is the reason for having to calibrate the device using a RSSI value from an iPhone 5?

Tags: ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am trying to do the calibration for my Samsung S6 Edge and S7 since they do not have ready values in the library. I have taken all the RSSI recordings for different distances, but I'm having trouble deciding on what to set as reference RSSI. My readings at 1 meter away from an iphone 5 are a lot different than the ones with an iphone 6 or the Samsung phones. This leads me to ask myself, why am I using an iPhone 5 reference since I will only be using my Samsung phones (or other Android phones) for this application? Wouldn't it be more accurate to set the reference value to the one read from the receiver device that we are currently calibrating?

Another issue that I'm having is that the predicted distance I obtain at the end of calibration becomes negative below 50cm actual distance. Does this mean that I am doing something wrong at this stage?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you calibrate using an iPhone is because all mobile devices have different bluetooth antennas and radio receiver gain characteristics.  This causes each to measure the same Bluetooth signal strength differently.  Only one device can be the standard.   An iPhone is chosen as the standard for measuring the 1 meter calibration value embedded in the beacon transmission for two reasons:

1. Historical: Apple's iPhone 4S was the first mobile device to support BLE beacons.
2. Abundance.  Some device must be used as the reference and the latest iPhone model tends to be the most widely available single device.

It is OK to use an iPhone as a reference when working toward a distance estimate on a Samsung device.  All that really matters is that you use a consistent reference.

Comment: So from what I understand, it doesn't matter what phone I am using to calculate the 1m reference as long as I use the same phone for every calibration during the experiment?

Comment: It *does matter*.  If you look at the calculations on this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ymREowDj40tYuA5CXd4IfC4WYPXxlx5hq1x8tQcWWCI/edit#gid=0, you will see that cell C9 is dependent on the value of A4, which is the iPhone calibration constant.  You need to know this because this will be transmitted by the beacon device, and is an input to the equation.